# How do I retrieve AJAX posted values using JSON string inside PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I cannot retrieve the values inside the PHP file sent as a JSON string.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //JavaScript Object
   var contact = {
      "client_email": $("#cleint_email").val(),
      "rep_name": $("#rep_name").val(),
      "rep_code": $("#rep_code").val(),
      "rep_email": $("#rep_email").val()
   }

   var contactStr = JSON.stringify(contact);

   //AJAX call
   $("#btnSend").bind("click", function() {
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/myphppage',
         data: { contactData: contactStr},
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(result) {
            alert(result.email);
         }
      });
   });
});
```

PHP file (`myphppage`):

```
<?php
$obj = $_POST['contactData'];
echo json_encode( array( "email" => $obj->client_email ) );
?>
```

No alert is popping up! What is the right way to retrieve JSON values inside PHP file?

Comment: Check console for any jquery error  else use json_decode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
  data: { "contactData": contactStr},
```

change your data property  to have quotes

also you can just pass  `data:contact`

and access it using `echo json_encode($_POST);`

or if your wanna play with the data `$abc['email']=$_POST["client_email"]` and so on

```
echo json_encode($abc);
```

Comment: side tip instead of using alert   use console.log(data); and hit f12 and switch tab to console

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php

$obj = json_decode($_POST['contactData'],true);
echo json_encode( array( "email" => $obj['client_email']));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the JSON object to a PHP variable for example;

```
$json = '{"foo": 12345}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo'}; // 12345
```

In your case;

```
$obj = $_POST['contactData'];
$data = json_decode($obj);
print $data->{'client_email'}
```